# Find out which one of the given numbers differs from the others for Javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop, indexing, split

I'm trying to solve this exercise. There is a string of numbers and among the given numbers the program finds one that is different in evenness, and returns a position of this number. The element has to be returned by its index (with the number being the actual position the number is in). If its index 0, it has to be returned as 1. I have this so far but it's not passing one test. I'm not too sure why because it feels like it should. Is anyone able to see what the error is? Any help is appreciated!

```
function iqTest(numbers) {
    var num = numbers.split(" ");
    var odd = 0;
    var even = 0;
    var position = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
        if(num[i]%2!==0) {
           odd++;
           if(odd===1) {
              position = num.indexOf(num[i]) + 1;
             }
        }
        else if(num[i]%2===0) {
           even++;
           if(even===1) {
           position = num.indexOf(num[i]) + 1;
            }
          }
    }
    return position;
}
iqTest("2 4 7 8 10") output 3
iqTest("2 1 2 2") output 2
iqTest("1 2 2") outputs 2 when it should be 1
```

Comment: please add the wanted results for all tests.

Comment: A tip for the future: before implementing an algorithm like this, consider using TDD. It will let you define the exact expectations for given inputs, e.g.
`it("should return -1 for empty string", () => {
    expect(iqTest("")).to.equal(-1);
});`
clearly defines what the algorithm needs to output if the input is empty. You write code that satisfies this condition and as you continue modifying it, always make sure all previously written tests pass. This will usually result in clean and less bug-prone code.

Answer (score 5):

The simplest way is to collect all even/odd positions in subarrays and check what array has the length 1 at the end:

```js
function iqTest(numbers) {
    numbers = numbers.split(' ');

    var positions = [[], []];

    for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        positions[numbers[i] % 2].push(i + 1);
    }

    if(positions[0].length === 1) return positions[0][0];
    if(positions[1].length === 1) return positions[1][0];

    return 0;


}

console.log(iqTest("2 4 7 8 10"))
console.log(iqTest("2 1 2 2"))
console.log(iqTest("1 2 2"))
console.log(iqTest("1 3 2 2"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is overly complex.

Since the first number determines whether you're looking for an even number or an odd one, calculate it separately. Then, find the first number that doesn't match it.

```
function iqTest(numbers) {
    numbers = numbers.split(" ");
    var parity = numbers.shift() % 2;
    for( var i=0; i<numbers.length; i++) {
        if( numbers[i] % 2 != parity) {
            return i+2; // 1-based, but we've also skipped the first
        }
    }
    return 0; // no number broke the pattern
}
```

That being said, `iqTest("1 2 2")` *should* return `2` because the number in position 2 (the first 2 in the string) is indeed the first number that breaks the parity pattern (which `1` has established to be odd)

Comment: "among the given numbers the program finds one that is different in evenness", so `1 2 2` should return 1.

Comment: @georg "different" in evenness. Meaning the first one can never be "different" since there's nothing to be different to yet!

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol the OP states that "iqTest("1 2 2") outputs 2 when it should be 1". That's the expectation and the program must satisfy it. Your assumption is wrong, I'm afraid.

Comment: @mingos While OP does say that, I feel it's actually the OP that has misunderstood what they're trying to do. Either that, or they've made it very unclear, as the question would simply be "find the position of the first number that is not even", in which case their attempt wouldn't include all that checking for odd numbers that behaves the same as the even number checks.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Here's how I see the issue: you have a sack of coloured balls, all red and one green. Select the one that differs from the others. It does not matter whether the green ball is the first one you pull out or the last one - it's still the one different from the rest. In the original post, the only difference is that instead of balls pulled sequentially from a sack, we have even and odd numbers.

Comment: @mingos Sure, but what evidence do you have that there will only ever be one green ball? You only have three examples in which this happens to be the case, but it's very common for programmers (especially newer ones, but veterans can too) to only test things they expect to happen, and not test things that may be unexpected.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol The OP does not specify whether it's guaranteed that the input is correct or not or, for that matter, what is considered correct input. What we know is that the input `"1 2 2"` is valid and is supposed to produce `1`.

Comment: @mingos I'm still not convinced OP is correct on that. From what I understand of the question, and the attempted code, `2` is indeed the correct answer because it is the first one where the parity is different.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol nothing in the original post indicates that the parity difference should take the order into account. What if we iterate from the end of the array? That would yield a different result for the same string were we to use your logic.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define which "evenness" is the different one. Use different counters for the two cases, and return -1 if you don't have a single different one. Something like this:

```
    function iqTest(numbers) {
    var num = numbers.split(" ");
    var odd = 0;
    var even = 0;
    var positionOdd = 0;
    var positionEven = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
       if(num[i]%2!==0) {
       odd++;
       if(odd===1) {
       positionOdd = i + 1;
         }
       }
       else if(num[i]%2===0) {
       even++;
       if(even===1) {
       positionEven = i + 1;
        }
      }
    }
    if (odd == 1)
       return positionOdd;
    else if (even == 1)
       return positionEven;
    else
       return -1;
   }
```

Note that, if you have exactly a single even number and a single odd one, the latter will be returned with the method of mine. Adjust the logic as your will starting from my solution.

Comment: Have you not noticed that `num.indexOf(num[i])` is just... `i`? Unless `num[i]` is not unique in the array, in which case it's wrong.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol: You are right. I edited the solution, but I agree that the OP's implementation (from which I started) is overly complex indeed.

Comment: @Andrea  Thanks for the help! I'm new to this, sorry for overly complex solution! Appreciate the explanations!

Comment: @padawan07: You're welcome ;) Glad that my explanation was clear enough!

Answer (score 0):

Since the first number determines whether you're looking for an even number or an odd one, calculate it separately. 
Then, find the first number that doesn't match it.

```
function iqTest(numbers){
   // ...
   const numArr = numbers.split(' ');

   const checkStatus = num => (parseInt(num) % 2) ? 'odd' : 'even';

   const findUniqueStatus = array => {
      let numEvens = 0;

      array.forEach(function(value){
         if (checkStatus(value) == 'even') { numEvens++; }
      });

      return (numEvens === 1) ? 'even' : 'odd'
   }

     let statuses = numArr.map(checkStatus),
     uniqueStatus = findUniqueStatus(numArr);

     return statuses.indexOf(uniqueStatus) + 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int Test(string numbers)
{
           var ints = numbers.Split(' ');
           var data = ints.Select(int.Parse).ToList();
           var unique = data.GroupBy(n => n % 2).OrderBy(c =>
           c.Count()).First().First();
           return data.FindIndex(c => c == unique) + 1;
        }
```

Comment: Please try to add a small description of how your answer presents the solution to the question. Its more helpful and does not take a lot more effort